# Populate a text field with value from a date field on the same entity

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7. I have 2 fields on a user entity, one is a date field from the date module (field_birthdaydate), and another is a textfield from the birthdays module (field_birthday).

I want users to enter their birthdays on the "field_birthdaydate" field, they will select the date and it appears like this: "16/03/2009"

I want this value to the be pre-populated on the "field_birthday" field as well (hidden from the users). I can achieve the field visibility part but I need help achieving the field pre-populate part.

My reason for doing this is because the birthdays module has some nice features and nice views filter support I can use in the future, but it is quite buggy at this stage to be used as a standalone birthday module, so I want to use it to store the birthday values for now, while using the date module to take the birthday input from users. When the birthdays module has finally fixed the pending issues, I will safely disable the date module and I wont be losing any birthday values.

I believe some custom code would help with this; when field field_birthdaydate is entered by user, populate field field_birthday with the same value before or during save. This is some pseudocode for what I want to achieve:

```
$user_input = "what the user will input";

if (field_birthdaydate == $user_input) {

set (field_birthday == field_birthdaydate);
}
```

Comment: Hi, we don't have a code writing service here - please write your own code after doing the appropriate research (the topic of populating fields programatically has been covered literally dozens of times before, you can easily find example code using Google or any other search engine). If you don't know PHP you'll need to do some work on learning that first. If you have issues with that code, _that's_ the right time to ask a question here. Make sure you include the actual code you're using (not pseudocode) so that we can help you with the specific problem you're facing. Thanks

Comment: maybe a pointer to some module that has this functionality would do then

Comment: I guess. You'll get a far better response if you make some effort though.